# Android Studio NDK being incompatible though having been set properly

Tags: java, c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface, ndk-build

I am trying to integrate OpenCv with android studio and in the process NDK issues are being faced by me .
The NDK always remains unselected in the Project Structure.The header files always remain unavailable because the path get unmentioned . I am trying to resolve this issue since days but not able to find the solution of the above if someone would help.
The NDK does not connect , though having been tried many ways to integrate NDK.
I had used all possible ways of integrating the NDK and have taken possible measure to replicate my needs but nothing works.
I have seen how others tried to resolve the issue but none of those worked for me.

Here below is my code
CMakeLists.txt file

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=gnu++11")

include_directories(${OpenCV_DIR}/jni/include)

add_library( lib_opencv SHARED IMPORTED )

set_target_properties(lib_opencv PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${OpenCV_DIR}/libs/${ANDROID_ABI}/libopencv_java4.so)

add_library( # Sets the name of the library.
             native-lib

             # Sets the library as a shared library.
             SHARED

             # Provides a relative path to your source file(s).
             native-lib.cpp )

find_library( # Sets the name of the path variable.
              log-lib

              # Specifies the name of the NDK library that
              # you want CMake to locate.
              log )

target_link_libraries( # Specifies the target library.
                       native-lib

                       # Links the target library to the log library
                       # included in the NDK.
                       ${log-lib}

                       lib_opencv)
```

native-lib.cpp

```
#include <jni.h>
```

Here above the jni.h file is linted to be not found and hence the JNIEXPORT and JNICALL also remains hidden.

build.gradle(app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.karuneshpalekar.copencv"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                cppFlags "-frtti -fexceptions"
                abiFilters 'x86', 'x86_64', 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a'
                arguments "-DOpenCV_DIR=" + opencvsdk + "/sdk/native"
            }
        }

        ndk {
            moduleName "test"
            cFlags "-std=c++11 -fexceptions"
            stl "gnustl_shared"
        }


    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path "src/main/cpp/CMakeLists.txt"
            version "3.10.2"
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        pickFirst 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_java4.so'
        pickFirst 'lib/arm64-v8a/libopencv_java4.so'
        pickFirst 'lib/x86/libopencv_java4.so'
        pickFirst 'lib/x86_64/libopencv_java4.so'
    }


}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0'
    implementation project(path: ':java')
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'

}
```

build.gradle(java)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

println "OpenCV: " + project.buildscript.sourceFile

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    //buildToolsVersion "x.y.z" // not needed since com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['src/main/jniLibs']
            java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['/build/master_pack-android/opencv/modules/java/android_sdk/android_gradle_lib/res']
            manifest.srcFile 'java/AndroidManifest.xml'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
}
```

Thank-You for helping
I have Ndk-rc21 and Android Studio AGP Version 4.0.1 and Gradle Versopion 6.1.1

Comment: This is not reddit, please describe the *problem* in the title; not "issue trolling".

Comment: Can you help me out with the above issue, any solutions to try ?

Comment: I have no idea what the actual error is. What is the output of `gradle assembleDebug` and does it look like it compiles your native code? Did you [link your native code to gradle](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/gradle-external-native-builds) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Issue I had was not with the NDK tool , it was with the directory where i had placed it.

There was space between file name which resulted in the error eg"User space Name".eg:C:/User/Elon Musk/SDK/ndk

I rectified this mistake of mine after a warning display by Android Studio lint .

I changed the Android SDK directory placement and rerun the code and the issue got resolved.

As per the answer above by Lakindu , there is no need for downgrading the Ndk library just make sure that the NDK is in the right place .

And also dont forget to add the NDK tool in the Project Structure which you can find by clicking Ctrl + Shift +Alt + S simultaneously.

Answer (score 2):

### How to use OpenCV SDK (v4.4) with NDK (v19)

Create an Android Studio project with an `app` module.

`settings.gradle`

```
include ':app'
```

`build.gradle`

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Set Android SDK and NDK (v19) paths in `local.properties` file.

```
sdk.dir=/home/USER/Android/Sdk
ndk.dir=/home/USER/Android/Sdk/ndk/android-ndk-r19c
```

Specify the path to the main cmake build script file, cmake version to use, and Android ABIs to compile in `app/build.gradle` file.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        ndk {
            abiFilters "arm64-v8a", "armeabi-v7a"
        }
    }

    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path "src/main/cpp/CMakeLists.txt"
            version "3.10.2"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    ...
}
```

Now we need header files and libraries from OpenCV Android SDK. So, download and extract OpenCV SDK (v4.4) package for Android from : https://opencv.org/releases/

Copy OpenCV header files and libraries from extracted package to the Android Studio project as follows.

1. Copy `OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/staticlibs/*` to `app/src/main/cpp/opencv/staticlibs/`
2. Copy `OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/3rdparty/*` to `app/src/main/cpp/opencv/3rdparty/`
3. Copy `OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/include/*` to `app/src/main/cpp/opencv/include/`

Create following cmake file in the project.

`app/src/main/cpp/opencv/opencv.cmake`

```
set( CURRENT_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR} )
set( OPENCV_INC_DIR ${CURRENT_DIR}/include )
set( OPENCV_LIBS_DIR ${CURRENT_DIR}/staticlibs/${ANDROID_ABI} )
set( THIRD_PARTY_LIBS_DIR ${CURRENT_DIR}/3rdparty/libs/${ANDROID_ABI} )

# Add opencv libs

set( lib_name opencv_calib3d )
add_library( ${lib_name} STATIC IMPORTED )
set_target_properties( ${lib_name} PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION "${OPENCV_LIBS_DIR}/lib${lib_name}.a" )
list( APPEND OPENCV_LIBS ${lib_name} )

set( lib_name opencv_dnn )
add_library( ${lib_name} STATIC IMPORTED )
set_target_properties( ${lib_name} PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION "${OPENCV_LIBS_DIR}/lib${lib_name}.a" )
list( APPEND OPENCV_LIBS ${lib_name} )

set( lib_name opencv_features2d )
add_library( ${lib_name} STATIC IMPORTED )
set_target_properties( ${lib_name} PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION "${OPENCV_LIBS_DIR}/lib${lib_name}.a" )
list( APPEND OPENCV_LIBS ${lib_name} )

set( lib_name opencv_flann )
add_library( ${lib_name} STATIC IMPORTED )
set_target_properties( ${lib_name} PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION "${OPENCV_LIBS_DIR}/lib${lib_name}.a" )
list( APPEND OPENCV_LIBS ${lib_name} )

set( lib_name opencv_gapi )
add_library( ${lib_name} STATIC IMPORTED )
set_target_properties( ${lib_name} PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION "${OPENCV_LIBS_DIR}/lib${lib_name}.a" )
list( APPEND OPENCV_LIBS ${lib_name} )

set( lib_name opencv_highgui )
add_library( ${lib_name} STATIC IMPORTED )
set_target_properties( ${lib_name} PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION "${OPENCV_LIBS_DIR}/lib${lib_name}.a" )
list( APPEND OPENCV_LIBS ${lib_name} )

set( lib_name opencv_imgcodecs )
add_library( ${lib_name} STATIC IMPORTED )
set_target_properties( ${lib_name} PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION "${OPENCV_LIBS_DIR}/lib${lib_name}.a" )
list( APPEND OPENCV_LIBS ${lib_name} )

set( lib_name opencv_imgproc )
add_library( ${lib_name} STATIC IMPORTED )
set_target_properties( ${lib_name} PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION "${OPENCV_LIBS_DIR}/lib${lib_name}.a" )
list( APPEND OPENCV_LIBS ${lib_name} )

set( lib_name opencv_ml )
add_library( ${lib_name} STATIC IMPORTED )
set_target_properties( ${lib_name} PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION "${OPENCV_LIBS_DIR}/lib${lib_name}.a" )
list( APPEND OPENCV_LIBS ${lib_name} )

set( lib_name opencv_objdetect )
add_library( ${lib_name} STATIC IMPORTED )
set_target_properties( ${lib_name} PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION "${OPENCV_LIBS_DIR}/lib${lib_name}.a" )
list( APPEND OPENCV_LIBS ${lib_name} )

set( lib_name opencv_photo )
add_library( ${lib_name} STATIC IMPORTED )
set_target_properties( ${lib_name} PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION "${OPENCV_LIBS_DIR}/lib${lib_name}.a" )
list( APPEND OPENCV_LIBS ${lib_name} )

set( lib_name opencv_stitching )
add_library( ${lib_name} STATIC IMPORTED )
set_target_properties( ${lib_name} PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION "${OPENCV_LIBS_DIR}/lib${lib_name}.a" )
list( APPEND OPENCV_LIBS ${lib_name} )

set( lib_name opencv_video )
add_library( ${lib_name} STATIC IMPORTED )
set_target_properties( ${lib_name} PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION "${OPENCV_LIBS_DIR}/lib${lib_name}.a" )
list( APPEND OPENCV_LIBS ${lib_name} )

set( lib_name opencv_videoio )
add_library( ${lib_name} STATIC IMPORTED )
set_target_properties( ${lib_name} PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION "${OPENCV_LIBS_DIR}/lib${lib_name}.a" )
list( APPEND OPENCV_LIBS ${lib_name} )

set( lib_name opencv_core )
add_library( ${lib_name} STATIC IMPORTED )
set_target_properties( ${lib_name} PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION "${OPENCV_LIBS_DIR}/lib${lib_name}.a" )
list( APPEND OPENCV_LIBS ${lib_name} )

# Add 3rd-party libs

set( lib_name ade )
add_library( ${lib_name} STATIC IMPORTED )
set_target_properties( ${lib_name} PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION "${THIRD_PARTY_LIBS_DIR}/lib${lib_name}.a" )
list( APPEND THIRD_PARTY_LIBS ${lib_name} )

set( lib_name cpufeatures )
add_library( ${lib_name} STATIC IMPORTED )
set_target_properties( ${lib_name} PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION "${THIRD_PARTY_LIBS_DIR}/lib${lib_name}.a" )
list( APPEND THIRD_PARTY_LIBS ${lib_name} )

set( lib_name IlmImf )
add_library( ${lib_name} STATIC IMPORTED )
set_target_properties( ${lib_name} PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION "${THIRD_PARTY_LIBS_DIR}/lib${lib_name}.a" )
list( APPEND THIRD_PARTY_LIBS ${lib_name} )

set( lib_name ittnotify )
add_library( ${lib_name} STATIC IMPORTED )
set_target_properties( ${lib_name} PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION "${THIRD_PARTY_LIBS_DIR}/lib${lib_name}.a" )
list( APPEND THIRD_PARTY_LIBS ${lib_name} )

set( lib_name libjasper )
add_library( ${lib_name} STATIC IMPORTED )
set_target_properties( ${lib_name} PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION "${THIRD_PARTY_LIBS_DIR}/lib${lib_name}.a" )
list( APPEND THIRD_PARTY_LIBS ${lib_name} )

set( lib_name libjpeg-turbo )
add_library( ${lib_name} STATIC IMPORTED )
set_target_properties( ${lib_name} PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION "${THIRD_PARTY_LIBS_DIR}/lib${lib_name}.a" )
list( APPEND THIRD_PARTY_LIBS ${lib_name} )

set( lib_name libpng )
add_library( ${lib_name} STATIC IMPORTED )
set_target_properties( ${lib_name} PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION "${THIRD_PARTY_LIBS_DIR}/lib${lib_name}.a" )
list( APPEND THIRD_PARTY_LIBS ${lib_name} )

set( lib_name libprotobuf )
add_library( ${lib_name} STATIC IMPORTED )
set_target_properties( ${lib_name} PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION "${THIRD_PARTY_LIBS_DIR}/lib${lib_name}.a" )
list( APPEND THIRD_PARTY_LIBS ${lib_name} )

set( lib_name libtiff )
add_library( ${lib_name} STATIC IMPORTED )
set_target_properties( ${lib_name} PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION "${THIRD_PARTY_LIBS_DIR}/lib${lib_name}.a" )
list( APPEND THIRD_PARTY_LIBS ${lib_name} )

set( lib_name libwebp )
add_library( ${lib_name} STATIC IMPORTED )
set_target_properties( ${lib_name} PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION "${THIRD_PARTY_LIBS_DIR}/lib${lib_name}.a" )
list( APPEND THIRD_PARTY_LIBS ${lib_name} )

set( lib_name quirc )
add_library( ${lib_name} STATIC IMPORTED )
set_target_properties( ${lib_name} PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION "${THIRD_PARTY_LIBS_DIR}/lib${lib_name}.a" )
list( APPEND THIRD_PARTY_LIBS ${lib_name} )

set( lib_name tbb )
add_library( ${lib_name} STATIC IMPORTED )
set_target_properties( ${lib_name} PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION "${THIRD_PARTY_LIBS_DIR}/lib${lib_name}.a" )
list( APPEND THIRD_PARTY_LIBS ${lib_name} )

set( lib_name tegra_hal )
add_library( ${lib_name} STATIC IMPORTED )
set_target_properties( ${lib_name} PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION "${THIRD_PARTY_LIBS_DIR}/lib${lib_name}.a" )
list( APPEND THIRD_PARTY_LIBS ${lib_name} )
```

Include `opencv.cmake` file in the main cmake build script, set OpenCV include directory, and link libraries as follows.

`app/src/main/cpp/CMakeLists.txt`

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

include( opencv/opencv.cmake )

find_library( log-lib log )
find_library( android-lib android )
find_library( jnigraphics-lib jnigraphics )
find_library( z-lib z )

add_library( native-lib SHARED
    native-lib.cpp
)

target_include_directories( native-lib PRIVATE
    ${OPENCV_INC_DIR}
)

target_link_libraries( native-lib
    ${log-lib}
    ${android-lib}
    ${jnigraphics-lib}
    ${OPENCV_LIBS}
    ${THIRD_PARTY_LIBS}
    ${z-lib}
)
```

Now you can use OpenCV APIs in your C++ source file.

`app/src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp`

```cpp
#include <jni.h>
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>

using namespace cv;

Mat matImage;
```

Comment: Regardless of OP's lack of clarity, a question of the form "I cannot get X to work, what is wrong?" should not be answered "here is a completely different solution Y" in my opinion.

Comment: Why NDK rc19 ? Aren't the recent released compatible to provide solution to the above error ?

Comment: Appreciate your Efforts .

Comment: KARUNESH PALEKAR, as @Botje has mentioned, your question is not clear. If this is the answer you expected, please edit the question accordingly.
When I write this answer, I just suspected that you might have stuck at setting up OpenCV's header files and native libraries with an Android Gradle project, because I faced that problem recently and could not find a proper guide online.